# JSch shell returns into StringArray

Tags: java, jsch

I am trying to relearn Java after 10 years of not touching it.  I want to create a library using JSch from some other apps I am looking to write.  I have the connections ironed out but I am using stdin and stdout right now.
I am looking to have a method that accepts a single command in a String and returns an ArrayList with the results.

Any assistance would be great!

```
//This vars are in the class.
private JSch _jsch;
private Session _session;
private Channel _channel;
```

Here is my connection method

```
public boolean Connect () throws JSchException
{
    try {
        _jsch = new JSch();
        _session = _jsch.getSession(_user, _hostname, _port);      
        _session.setPassword(_password);
        _session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");  

        _channel = _session.openChannel("shell");

        //((ChannelShell)_channel).setPtyType("vt100");

        _channel.setInputStream(bais);
        _channel.setOutputStream(baos);
        _channel.connect(3000);                     
    }//try to connect
    catch (JSchException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The goal is once I open the connection I can send this method a command and return the results in an array.  Act based on the results and send more commands.  I don't want to close the connection each time as they will build on the commands that come before it. I am not sure how to work with the Inputs and Output Streams enough to get the results I am looking for.  If you can assist with filling out the following method, I would be grateful.

```
public List<String> ExecuteCommand (String command) {
    //run command to existing connection
    //Get returned lines to Array List and return the list
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You want to take a multi-line String (command) and create an ArrayList of lines? That's all?

Comment: Pretty much.  I am just unsure how to deal with the streams in java at this point.  My goal is to do the following.

    List<Array> results = ExecuteCommand ("ps -ef");

I know the ps -ef will return a lot of lines so I would like to get that into an array or ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of running a local process and creating a return `ArrayList` filled line by line with the output from the process. Whilst it's not exactly what you want, it should give you an idea.

```
public List<String> ExecuteCommand (String command) {
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = r.exec(command);
    p.waitFor();
    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";
    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
        output.add(line);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created an [open source project (click to see)](https://github.com/stanleyxu2005/linop) to implements remote file system. Here is the most important code snippet, which also supports `sudo`. In the example, I redirect error output to standard output. *If you do not want the error output, you can remove it.* In the example, I use StringWriter instead of List<String>. I encourage you to use it.

```
/**
 * Executes commands at target host.
 * @throws IOException Failed to capture a return code
 */
public int exec(boolean sudo, String command, StringWriter output) throws IOException {
    ChannelExec channel = null;
    try {
        channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
        sudo = sudo && !username.equals("root");
        if (sudo) {
            command = "sudo -S -p '' " + command;
            channel.setPty(true);
        }
        channel.setCommand(command);

        InputStream stdout = channel.getInputStream(); // The stream will be recycled automatically
        InputStream stderr = channel.getErrStream(); // The stream will be recycled automatically
        channel.connect();

        boolean passwordEntered = false;
        if (sudo && !StringUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            OutputStream stdin = channel.getOutputStream();
            stdin.write(password.getBytes());
            stdin.write("\n".getBytes());
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(stdin);
            passwordEntered = true;
        }

        String contents = readFully(stdout);
        if (passwordEntered) {
            contents = contents.substring(password.length());
        }
        output.write(contents.trim());
        contents = readFully(stderr);

        int retval = channel.getExitStatus();
        if (retval != 0) {
            output.append(contents.trim());
        }
        return retval;
    }
    catch (JSchException ex) {
        throw new IOException(ex);
    }
    finally {
        output.flush();
        if (channel != null) {
            channel.disconnect();
        }
    }
}

private static String readFully(InputStream input) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    int bytesRead = input.read();
    while (bytesRead != -1) {
        output.append((char) bytesRead);
        bytesRead = input.read();
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I have currently.  It could use some stream lining and clean up but it is getting me what I am looking for.

I didn't want to mark this as an answer but I haven't posted to this site before so excuse me if I did that wrong.  Here is the new connect method

```
public boolean Connect () throws JSchException
{
    try {
        _jsch = new JSch();
        _session = _jsch.getSession(_user, _hostname, _port);      
        _session.setPassword(_password);
        _session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");  

        _session.connect();
        _channel = _session.openChannel("shell");

        _channel.setInputStream(null);

        _isInput = _channel.getInputStream();
        _isOutput = _channel.getOutputStream();

        _reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(_isInput));
        _writer = new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter (_isOutput));

        _channel.connect(3000);   

        LastLogin = _reader.readLine(); //get last login message
    }//try to connect
    catch (JSchException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee)
    {
        return false;
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is my execute method.  I know there is a better way to get from the char[] to an ArrayList but I haven't ironed that out just yet.

```
public List<String> ExecuteCommand (String command)
{

    List<String> returns = new ArrayList();
    try {
        _writer.write(command);


        if ( !command.endsWith("\n") )
            _writer.write("\n");

        _writer.flush();
        Thread.sleep(2000); //allow time to exec

        int c;
        StringBuilder response= new StringBuilder();

        while (_reader.ready()) {
            c = _reader.read();
            if (c == -1)
                break;
            response.append( (char)c ) ;  
        }//while

        String[] lines = response.toString().split("\n");
        for (String line: lines)
        {
            if (line.trim().length()!=0)
                returns.add(line);
        }

    }//try
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        //handle this later
    }//catch
    catch (InterruptedException ie)
    {
        //handle this later
    }
    return returns;
}//ExecuteCommand
```

I know it isn't great but it works.